# Is defining colours by name safe nowdays?

Tags: html, css, colors

Many colors on CSS can be defined by name. [neilorangepeel site](http://colours.neilorangepeel.com/). has a list of the colors along with their names.

I remember had heard on the past that the colours should never be defined by the name, but instead using the numbers. I heard that the browsers codified the color names differently. So:

1. It was really not safe to define colors by names on the past? and
2. Is it safe to define colors by the name nowdays?

Comment: I added the HTML tag because technically those colors aren't really CSS ones (even if most of us today would not put a colour outside of a style file).

Comment: @dystroy: I don't think that site is referencing the HTML spec though. Your answer references the CSS spec as well.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, of course, but the list of 140 colours date from a time when almost nobody did CSS and technically they're more related to HTML than CSS. But if you feel it's better to leave the tags as they were, no problem with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lists of [basic color names](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4) and of [extended color names](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) normalized by the w3.org.

Use the colors of thoses lists and you're fine. The rule you give (*"colours should never be defined by the name"*) doesn't seem to have any basis as all browsers respect this standard (the 140 colours weren't really normalized, apart the 17 "standard" ones, in old HTML specifications but were already available in all browsers, you find the same colours in the [venerable Netscape list of colours](http://www.ou.edu/research/electron/internet/bgcolors.shtml)).

The site you link to seems to use those colors.

Comment: Do you have any idea when IE started to support those colors? Now that I know that the name is "extended color keywords", still hard to find on the internet

Comment: It's old enough, IE followed what made Netscape, at that time.